# Excluding content from ASP.NET master page in other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

is it possible to exclude layout (header, sidebar and footer) from content page that inherit master page?
I'm asking because of situation with repeated layout:

[image]

In master there is a structure like this:

```
<body>
<!-- HEADER -->

<!-- Menu -->
<!-- CONTENT -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
                                <div>
                                    <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:contentplaceholder>
                                </div>
                            </form>
<!-- FOOTER -->
</body>
```

and in content page (.aspx) there is a structure

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Site.WebBasePage"
    EnableEventValidation="false" JFormID="Form" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<j:Tab Name="Tab2" runat="server" ID="detail">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="detail" frameborder="0" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
            </j:Tab>

</asp:Content>
```

In the code above there is a call for another aspx file where is the detail form.

Comment: Take it out of the master page, make a new 'sub' master page which inherts the main one and use that elsewhere

Comment: How to use it elsewhere? I'm trying with contentplaceholder, but it won't render content :/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide content  place holder which you dont want to display on your content page by below code

//get the master page of current page

From here you can find the relevant place holder like this:

```
PlaceHolder objPlaceHolder = this.Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderID") as PlaceHolder;
if(objPlaceHolder == null)
{
    // doesn't exist content place holder.
}
else
{
    objPlaceHolder.Visible = false;
}
```

This will hide the content place holder of master page in child page